# Is it possible to specify that a function argument must be a string literal?

Tags: rust

This fragment refuses to compile because `format!()` won't touch non-literal strings.

```
fn cond_format<T: std::fmt::Display>(cond: bool, fmt_str: &'static str, item: T) -> String {
    if cond {
        format!(fmt_str, item)
    } else {
        format!("{}", item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a macro for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Macros are expanded before types, names, or values even exist.  There's no possible way for that to work.  As a result, there's no reason for the language to distinguish between literals and non-literals at runtime: even if there *was*, nothing would be able to use that information.

You *have* to use a macro.  Below are two plausible ways of doing this.

```
macro_rules! cond_format {
    ($fmt_str:expr) => {
        |cond: bool, item| -> String {
            if cond {
                format!($fmt_str, item)
            } else {
                format!("{}", item)
            }
        }
    };

    ($cond:expr, $fmt_str:expr, $item:expr) => {
        if $cond {
            format!($fmt_str, $item)
        } else {
            format!("{}", $item)
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", cond_format!("{:x}")(false, 42));
    println!("{}", cond_format!(true, "{:x}", 42));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/), this is not possible:

> (...) you can see that the first argument is a format string. It
>   is required by the compiler for this to be a string literal; it cannot
>   be a variable passed in (in order to perform validity checking).

Comment: Isn't that OPs question though? Because `format` has the restriction, they'd like some way of saying that `cond_format` can only takes literals. (I'm pretty sure the answer "no" is the correct one though, it's mostly the rationale I'm quibbling with).

Comment: But in my case I'm not looking to use `fmt_str` as a variable; I'm trying to do the exact opposite.

Comment: I understood the question as "is there a way for a function to receive a string literal and use it as the format string in a `format!()` macro inside it?" and the answer to that is no - this is not possible using a function.